# Bootstrap drop down Sub menu issues

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular6

[image]

I am facing some issues in my application. in this image you can see

```
element.style{ top:5px, left:157.3px} for **ul**
```

I am looking for this same logic how they are calculating? I want this logic for my scroll able drop down.